# Recover accidentally deleted overwritten data

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

I have a Kingston 64 GB microSD card that I've accidentally chosen for a the Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool to format and write the Windows installation disk data on it instead of another USB flash. Unfortunately, I've realized that when the process was finished. My microSD card had around 7 GB free, so I believe that some data have been overwritten by the written Windows installation disk data. I'm looking for a way to recover all the lost data including the overwritten ones.

However, it's not possible to recover data on an HDD. I've read [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/53257) that there's a possibility to recover overwritten data (even the securely deleted overwritten ones with complicated passes) on SSD. So I think the answer for this question should have different bases as it may be possible for SD also to restore the overwritten data. We just need a specialized way that could do this specifically, which should take a different process from an HDD.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Storage medium is a `microSD card` which is physically different from an `HDD`. I've read [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/53257) that there's a possibility to restore overwritten data, even the securely deleted overwritten ones, on SSD. So I think the answer for this question should have different bases as it may be possible for SD also to restore overwritten data in this case, just we need a specialized way that could do this specifically which is a different process from an HDD.

Comment: Data recovery is driven by **file system** & be it microSD, flash drive, HDD or SSD they pretty much follow the same principle. Have you tried any of the tools suggested in the answer ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like No, I've tried [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) and [EaseUS](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizardpro/drwpro-unlimited.htm) which I think they follow the same process.

Comment: The post you linked to talks about the potential ability to recover data in a lab if you have a lot of very expensive resources.  It isn't something you can do running a piece of consumer software.  The low-level recovery you have already done is as good as you can do at home.

Comment: yea the special ways are to read the data on the nand chips direct with opening it up and connecting to the chips, and powering them and all completly minus the controller.a way more sofisticated electronics project than writing a blog about it existing there :-)